# Feeding data to database with PHP fails

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I have a PHP script supposed to insert data to a database on a web server. I got around 360 records. If I run the script only inserting one or two columns everything is OK. If i run the script feeding 10 columns or more, the script stop at 20-50 records. Why is this, and what can I do to make the script insert all records and all columns?

This is the first script, working perfectly:

```php
<?php


$tilkobling = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($tilkobing->connect_error) { //Mislykket DV-tilkobling
    die("Kunne ikke koble til database.");
  }



$kommune_api_url = "https://register.geonorge.no/api/sosi-kodelister/kommunenummer.json?";
$kommune_api_response = file_get_contents($kommune_api_url);
$kommune_api_data = json_decode($kommune_api_response,true);

$kommune_antall = $kommune_api_data['ContainedItemsResult']['Count'];

// LEGGER TIL KOMMUNENUMMER I DB.
for ($kom = 0; $kom <= $kommune_antall; $kom++) {
    $kommunenummer = $kommune_api_data['containeditems'][$kom]['codevalue'];
    $kommune_navn = $kommune_api_data['containeditems'][$kom]['description'];

    // Legger til kommunenummer i kommunenummer
    $sql = "INSERT INTO kommuneinfo (kommunenummer, kommunenavn)
    VALUES ($kommunenummer, '$kommune_navn')";

    if (mysqli_query($tilkobling, $sql)) {
    echo "";
    } else {
    echo "Error! Kommunenummer" . $kommunenummer . " / " . $kommune_navn . " ble ikke oppdatert.<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    }

?>
```

When reading from another API and inserting much more data this is the script, which fails after 20-50 insertions:

```php
<?php


$servername = "xxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$dbname = "xxxx";

$tilkobling = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($tilkobing->connect_error) { //Mislykket DV-tilkobling
    die("Kunne ikke koble til database.");
  }



$kommune_api_url = "https://register.geonorge.no/api/sosi-kodelister/kommunenummer.json?";
$kommune_api_response = file_get_contents($kommune_api_url);
$kommune_api_data = json_decode($kommune_api_response,true);

$kommune_antall = $kommune_api_data['ContainedItemsResult']['Count'];

// LEGGER TIL KOMMUNENUMMER I DB.
for ($kom = 0; $kom <= 360; $kom++) {
    $kommune = $kommune_api_data['containeditems'][$kom]['codevalue'];
    $kommune_navn = $kommune_api_data['containeditems'][$kom]['description'];
    
    if ($kommune != "2211") {
        echo $kommune_navn . "<br>";
        echo $kom . "<br>";
    
        $url = "https://data.ssb.no/api/v0/no/table/06913/";
    
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    
        $headers = array(
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    
        $data = <<<DATA
        {
        "query": [
            {
            "code": "Region",
            "selection": {
                "filter": "agg:KommSummerHist",
                "values": [
                "K_$kommune"
                ]
            }
            },
            {
            "code": "ContentsCode",
            "selection": {
                "filter": "item",
                "values": [
                "Folkemengde"
                ]
            }
            },
            {
            "code": "Tid",
            "selection": {
                "filter": "item",
                "values": [
                "1970",
                "1971",
                "1972",
                "1973",
                "1974",
                "1975",
                "1976",
                "1977",
                "1978",
                "1979",
                "1980",
                "1981",
                "1982",
                "1983",
                "1984",
                "1985",
                "1986",
                "1987",
                "1988",
                "1989",
                "1990",
                "1991",
                "1992",
                "1993",
                "1994",        
                "1995",
                "1996",
                "1997",
                "1998",
                "1999",
                "2000",
                "2001",
                "2002",
                "2003",
                "2004",
                "2005",
                "2006",
                "2007",
                "2008",
                "2009",
                "2010",
                "2011",
                "2012",
                "2013",
                "2014",
                "2015",
                "2016",
                "2017",
                "2018",
                "2019",
                "2020",
                "2021"
                ]
            }
            }
        ],
        "response": {
            "format": "json-stat2"
        }
        }
        DATA;
    
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    
        //for debug only!
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    
        $resp = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        //var_dump($resp);
    
        $test = json_decode($resp, true);
        $befolkning1970 = $test['value'][0];
        $befolkning1971 = $test['value'][1];
        $befolkning1972 = $test['value'][2];
        $befolkning1973 = $test['value'][3];
        $befolkning1974 = $test['value'][4];
        $befolkning1975 = $test['value'][5];
        $befolkning1976 = $test['value'][6];
        $befolkning1977 = $test['value'][7];
        $befolkning1978 = $test['value'][8];
        $befolkning1979 = $test['value'][9];
        $befolkning1980 = $test['value'][10];
        $befolkning1981 = $test['value'][11];
        $befolkning1982 = $test['value'][12];
        $befolkning1983 = $test['value'][13];
        $befolkning1984 = $test['value'][14];
        $befolkning1985 = $test['value'][15];
        $befolkning1986 = $test['value'][16];
        $befolkning1987 = $test['value'][17];
        $befolkning1988 = $test['value'][18];
        $befolkning1989 = $test['value'][19];
        $befolkning1990 = $test['value'][20];
        $befolkning1991 = $test['value'][21];
        $befolkning1992 = $test['value'][22];
        $befolkning1993 = $test['value'][23];
        $befolkning1994 = $test['value'][24];
        $befolkning1995 = $test['value'][25];
        $befolkning1996 = $test['value'][26];
        $befolkning1997 = $test['value'][27];
        $befolkning1998 = $test['value'][28];
        $befolkning1999 = $test['value'][29];
        $befolkning2000 = $test['value'][30];
        $befolkning2001 = $test['value'][31];
        $befolkning2002 = $test['value'][32];
        $befolkning2003 = $test['value'][33];
        $befolkning2004 = $test['value'][34];
        $befolkning2005 = $test['value'][35];
        $befolkning2006 = $test['value'][36];
        $befolkning2007 = $test['value'][37];
        $befolkning2008 = $test['value'][38];
        $befolkning2009 = $test['value'][39];
        $befolkning2010 = $test['value'][40];
        $befolkning2011 = $test['value'][41];
        $befolkning2012 = $test['value'][42];
        $befolkning2013 = $test['value'][43];
        $befolkning2014 = $test['value'][44];
        $befolkning2015 = $test['value'][45];
        $befolkning2016 = $test['value'][46];
        $befolkning2017 = $test['value'][47];
        $befolkning2018 = $test['value'][48];
        $befolkning2019 = $test['value'][49];
        $befolkning2020 = $test['value'][50];
    
    
    
    
    
    
        // Legger til kommunenummer i kommunenummer
        $sql = "UPDATE kommuneinfo
        set befolkning1970 = $befolkning1970,
        befolkning1975 = $befolkning1975,
        befolkning1980 = $befolkning1980,
        befolkning1985 = $befolkning1985,
        befolkning1990 = $befolkning1990,
        befolkning1995 = $befolkning1995,
        befolkning2000 = $befolkning2000,
        befolkning2005 = $befolkning2005,
        befolkning2010 = $befolkning2010,
        befolkning2015 = $befolkning2015,
        befolkning2020 = $befolkning2020
        WHERE kommunenummer = $kommune";
    
    
    
    
    
    
        if (mysqli_query($tilkobling, $sql)) {
        echo "";
        } else {
        echo "Error! Kommunenummer" . $kommune . " / " . $kommune_navn . " ble ikke oppdatert.<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
        } 
    }

echo "<br>Ferdig";



?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code.

First I got rid of all the database-related stuff, because I don't think the problem is the database. Then I added [curl_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php), like this:

```
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
echo curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

because I suspect that curl is the real problem. And indeed I get a nice error back after 61 calls:

> {"error":"429 - Too many requests in too short timeframe. Please try
> again later."}.

That's because you try to make 360 requests in a loop. The API doesn't like that.

I've a bit further away from Norway, so my calls are done a bit slower and it takes a bit longer to reach the limit than it did with you. This hints at an easy and lazy way to solve this problem. You could add a long enough [usleep()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usleep) inside the loop to slow it down just enough so you don't hit the limit.

A better way to solve this problem would be if it was possible to make less calls to get the same data. I don't know if this is possible, but my guess is that it is.